# Hi I create a javafx application where specific images should be cropped to a specific size

Tags: java, image

in javafx I would need a class that cuts something out of a given image eg the image would have to be cropped to 1500x1000px and 800x600 in a similar way to uploading a facebook profile picture so that you can freely drag the picture from which part to cut

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using mouse drag events to set the viewPort on an image view, the viewPort in an image view tells the ImageView which part of the image to render, using a 2D rectangle.

In this example, I created a class (named it ImageCropper), which will receive the target dimensions in the constructor to create an ImageView to represent the cropped image and handle mouse events to re-position the viewPort, (the background image and border are for visual polish and are optional)

[image]

```
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.geometry.Rectangle2D;
import javafx.scene.effect.ColorAdjust;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.StrokeType;

public class ImageCropper extends StackPane {
    private double initX, initY;
    private double initOffX, initOffY;
    private double offX, offY;

    private ImageView view;

    public ImageCropper(Image image, double targetWidth, double targetHeight) {
        setMaxSize(targetWidth, targetHeight);
        setMinSize(targetWidth, targetHeight);
        setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

        Rectangle border = new Rectangle(targetWidth, targetHeight);
        border.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        border.setStrokeWidth(6);
        border.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        border.setStrokeType(StrokeType.INSIDE);
        border.setStrokeDashOffset(20);
        border.getStrokeDashArray().setAll(40.0, targetHeight - 40, 40.0, targetWidth - 40);
        border.setMouseTransparent(true);

        ImageView backgroundImageView = new ImageView(image);
        ColorAdjust effect = new ColorAdjust();
        effect.setBrightness(-.5);
        backgroundImageView.setEffect(effect);

        view = new ImageView(image);
        view.setFitWidth(targetWidth);
        view.setFitHeight(targetHeight);

        offX = image.getWidth() / 2 - (targetWidth / 2);
        offY = image.getHeight() / 2 - (targetHeight / 2);
        view.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(offX, offY, targetWidth, targetHeight));

        backgroundImageView.setTranslateX(-offX);
        backgroundImageView.setTranslateY(-offY);

        view.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
            initX = e.getSceneX();
            initY = e.getSceneY();
            initOffX = offX;
            initOffY = offY;
        });

        view.setOnMouseDragged(e -> {
            offX = Math.min(image.getWidth() - targetWidth, Math.max(0, initOffX + (initX - e.getSceneX())));
            offY = Math.min(image.getHeight() - targetHeight, Math.max(0, initOffY + (initY - e.getSceneY())));

            view.setViewport(new Rectangle2D(offX, offY, targetWidth, targetHeight));

            backgroundImageView.setTranslateX(-offX);
            backgroundImageView.setTranslateY(-offY);
        });

        getChildren().addAll(backgroundImageView, view, border);
    }

    public Image getCroppedImage() {
        return view.snapshot(null, null);
    }
}
```

---

Using it in your app would involve calling the constructor with an image and the target dimensions you want to crop to

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage ps) {
        VBox root = new VBox(20);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(20));

        Image image = new Image(Test.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("test.png"));
        ImageCropper cropper = new ImageCropper(image, 800, 600);

        Button crop = new Button("Crop");

        crop.setOnAction(e-> {
            Stage disp = new Stage();

            disp.setScene(new Scene(new StackPane(new ImageView(cropper.getCroppedImage()))));

            disp.show();
        });

        root.getChildren().setAll(cropper, crop);

        ps.setScene(new Scene(root));
        ps.show();
    }
}
```

(Note 1: I don't know if there is a better method to get the cropped image, in this example I'm taking a snapshot of the ImageView which works fine but I feel uncomfortable doing that, would help if you know better methods)

(Note 2: this method would probably break if the image you pass to the ImageCropper is smaller than the target size, fixing that would involve down-scaling the target size while preserving its ratio, or up-scaling the image to be bigger than the target size)